# how to extract content of value rather than its type in python 2.7

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I am trying to extract the value from a key in a json file. Its type is dict, but instead of extracting the content after testing for the key being present, I am only getting `{'name_of_key': <type 'dict'>}`. How can I successfully extract the actual content instead? My code is:

```
    with open("a.json", 'r') as infile, open("b.json", 'w') as outfile:
        key = "name_of_key"

            for key in infile:
            value = {"name_of_key": dict} 
                if key is not None:
                    outfile.write(str(value))
```

The json file looks like this, and I want to extract everything after "name_of_key":

```
{
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "/linkxxx"
        }
    },
    "metadata": {
        "name_of_key": {
            "key": {
                "key3s": "eighteen"
            },
            "key": "company",
            "modelItems": {
                "key1": "1",
                "key2": "2",
                "key0": "0"

            }
        },
        "contentType": "type_of_media"
    }
}
```

Comment: But... what do you think `dict` refers to in your code? You haven't done anything at all to parse the JSON or refer to any of its values.

Comment: mydictionary = {"name_of_key": {}}

Comment: Thanks @DanielRoseman, that is the core issue I am confused about. What follows in the dictionary after "name_of_key" is the value for that key, and that content is what I'm trying to refer to with dict. That is, I'm trying to name the value and then extract it.

Comment: But `mydictionary` has nothing to do with the JSON in that file you just opened. There is no relationship between "name_of_key" in mydictionary and "name_of_key" in the JSON data. As I said, you haven't even parsed that data into Python, or assigned it to anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several issues in your code.

#### Use the `json` module

The Python standard library comes with a module called `json` which helps you parse JSON text into a Python object, and serialize a Python object into JSON. Its documentation, for Python version 2.7, is [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html). Specifically, take a look at the functions `json.load` and `json.dump`.

#### What is `dict` in this line?

Secondly, I don't understand what your intention is in this line:

```
mydictionary = {"name_of_key": dict}
```

In Python, [`dict()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict) is a constructor function used to create a dictionary (you can see how it can be used in the [examples in the documenation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict)).

If you meant to use `dict()` to contruct a dictionary, you should pass some argument to it.

If you meant to use `dict` as a variable name (but where is its definition?), don't do that because that definition hides the globally defined [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict) name.

#### The reason you get `<type 'dict'>`

`dict` is a class name. You get `<type 'dict'>` also if you fire up the Python interpreter and do this:

```
>>> print dict
<type 'dict'>
```

Here `dict` is not a dictionary **value**, but the constructor function to create a dictionary.

To print an actual dictonary value:

```
>>> a = dict([('one', 1), ('two', 2)])
>>> print a
{'two': 2, 'one': 1}
```

Or more simply, like this, which is the same:

```
>>> a = {'one': 1, 'two': 2}
>>> print a
{'two': 2, 'one': 1}
```

#### How to extract the inner dictionary

```
import json

def extract_metadata(input_filename, output_filename, wanted_key):
    with open(input_filename, 'r') as infile:
        data = json.load(infile)

    with open(output_filename, 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(data['metadata'][wanted_key], outfile)

extract_metadata('a.json', 'b.json', 'name_of_key')
```

Comment: Thank you for this detailed explanation, which is going to be extremely useful and helpful to me. Your code works perfectly and I have exactly what i need now. Thanks again.

Comment: I need to modify the code to include not just the value, but also the key, i.e. "metadata" needs to be included. I tried                                                     `for key in my_dict.keys():
       if key is "metadata":
            val = my_dict[key]
            print key,val                                                                                     
 but although this works in ipython, when I add it to the function I get 'global name val is not defined'--I set it as a global variable earlier. Could you suggest a fix for this?